# Animate UILabel text color with CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uilabel

I am new to CALayer's class, i am trying to create label with gradient color with animation,
so ai have seen **CAGradientLayer** & **CABasicAnimation**

```
CAGradientLayer *grad=[CAGradientLayer layer];
grad.frame=self.lbl.bounds;

UIColor *ac1=[UIColor purpleColor];
UIColor *ac2=[UIColor yellowColor];
UIColor *ac3=[UIColor blueColor];
grad.colors=@[(id)[ac2 CGColor],(id)[ac2 CGColor],(id)[ac3 CGColor]];

CABasicAnimation *anim2=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"colors"];
anim2.toValue=@[(id)ac1.CGColor,(id)ac2.CGColor,(id)ac2.CGColor];
anim2.duration=4.0;
anim2.autoreverses=YES;
anim2.repeatCount=1e100;
[grad addAnimation:anim2 forKey:@"colors"];

[[self.lbl layer] insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

currently it animates label background , how can i animate it to text?? It doesnt show text also??

**I dont want to use some custom library for that.**

Comment: I would assume this is doing something similar https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer

Comment: @sbarow: not exactly like this.

Comment: see this http://corecocoa.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/animatable-text-color-of-uilabel/#more-30